# I hava a question about Firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a question about Firestore in Flutter because I have an impasse in my app because I have a login page where there are the fields Country, email and password for login and I would like to be able to authenticate the user using these 3 fields but when I need to use the country via Firestore I cannot retrieve it and this field is used in validation, it seems to me that for you to retrieve a field from Firestore you cannot exit via Firebase Auth as you need currentUser to access the field, I found This is strange and I'm not able to do this logic where it first checks if the user is authenticated and then accesses the country field in Firebase and validates the login. Has anyone ever done something similar?

this my loginPage

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/Pages/reset_page.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/Pages/sign_up.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/auth/auth_page.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/components/dropdown_button.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/components/text_field.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String? name;
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  bool obscureText = true;
  String? _selectedCountry;  
  String? countryValue;
  String? errorMessage;
  String? errorMessageEmail;
  String? errorMessagePassword;
  String? errorMessageCountry;
  final AuthPage _authPage = AuthPage();  
  

  _validateFields() async {
    String email = _emailController.text;
    String password = _passwordController.text;     

    if (_selectedCountry == 'United Kingdom') {
      if (email.isNotEmpty && email.contains("@")) {
        if (password.isNotEmpty) {
          errorMessage = null;
          errorMessageEmail = null;
          errorMessagePassword = null;
          signUserIn();
        } else {
          setState(() {
            errorMessagePassword = 'Please enter your password';
          });
        }
      } else {
        setState(() {
          errorMessageEmail = 'Please enter your E-mail ';
        });
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        errorMessage = 'Please enter your country';
      });
    }
  }

  signUserIn() async {
    String email = _emailController.text;
    String password = _passwordController.text;         
   
    String? authResult = await _authPage.loginUser(
        context, mounted, email, password);   
            
    setState(() {
      errorMessage = authResult;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF101d25),
            appBar: AppBar(
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                toolbarHeight: deviceHeight < 500
                    ? deviceHeight * 0.15
                    : deviceHeight * 0.09,
                centerTitle: true,
                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF101d25),
                title: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: Text('Verify your E-mail',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF0ca886),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ),
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: Color(0xFF0ca886)),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ]),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: deviceHeight < 500
                      ? deviceHeight * 1.30
                      : deviceHeight * 0.80,
                  width: deviceWidth < 500
                      ? deviceWidth * 0.80
                      : deviceWidth * 0.60,
                  child: Column(
                    //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          'WhatsApp will verify your registred\n e-mail. Enter your country, e-mail and password:',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.05),
                      Form(
                        key: formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            CustomDropDownButton(
                              value: _selectedCountry,
                              onChanged: (newValue) {
                                _selectedCountry = newValue;
                              },
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.03),
                            CustomTextField(
                              labelText: 'E-mail',
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              controller: _emailController,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                if (value.isNotEmpty && value.contains("@")) {
                                  errorMessageEmail = null;
                                }
                              },
                              errorText: errorMessageEmail,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.02),
                            CustomTextField(
                              labelText: 'Password',
                              suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    obscureText = !obscureText;
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: deviceHeight < 500
                                          ? deviceHeight * 0.055
                                          : deviceHeight * 0.025),
                                  child: FaIcon(
                                      obscureText
                                          ? FontAwesomeIcons.solidEye
                                          : FontAwesomeIcons.solidEyeSlash,
                                      color: const Color(0xFF0ca886),
                                      size: 22),
                                ),
                              ),
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                              obscureText: obscureText,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                                  errorMessagePassword = null;
                                }
                              },
                              controller: _passwordController,
                              errorText: errorMessagePassword,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.02),
                      RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(children: [
                          TextSpan(
                              text: 'Forgot your password?',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 15),
                              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                ..onTap = () {
                                  //print('reset password');
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              const ResetPasswordPage()));
                                }),
                        ]),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.01),
                      Text(
                        errorMessage ??
                            '', // Exibe a mensagem de erro ou uma string vazia
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color:
                              Colors.red, // Cor vermelha para indicar um erro
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.01),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: deviceHeight < 500
                            ? deviceHeight * 0.15
                            : deviceHeight * 0.06,
                        width: deviceWidth < 500
                            ? deviceWidth * 0.68
                            : deviceWidth * 0.38,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                              ),
                              backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0ca886)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _validateFields();
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: deviceWidth * 0.012),
                            child: const Text(
                              'Enter',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF121a21), fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: deviceHeight * 0.02),
                        child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(children: [
                          const TextSpan(
                              text: "Don't have a account yet?  ",
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14)),
                          TextSpan(
                              text: 'SignUp.',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                ..onTap = () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              const SignupPage()));
                                }),
                        ])),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here my AuthPage

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/Pages/home.dart';

class AuthPage {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;   

  Future loginUser(
      BuildContext context, bool mounted, String email, String password) async {
    try {
      // Exibe um CircularProgress antes de Autenticar
      showCircularIndicator(context);

      // await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 5000));
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      if (!mounted) return;
          Navigator.pop(context);
          _navigateToNextScreen(context);
      
      // Pegar o usuario atual caso autenticado
      /*
      User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        // Usuário está autenticado, agora você pode acessar o campo país
        String? country = await getCountryForUser(user);        
        if (country != null) {         
          if (!mounted) return;
          Navigator.pop(context);
          _navigateToNextScreen(context);
          
        } else{
          return null;
        }
        // Faça o que precisa ser feito com o campo país
      } else {
        // Usuário não autenticado
        print('Usuário não autenticado');
      }
      */

      // Se a autenticação for bem-sucedida, navegue para a próxima tela
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // Esconde o circularIndicator
      if (!mounted) return;
      Navigator.pop(context);
      // Se houver um erro, chame a função de retorno de erro
      if (e.code == 'invalid-credential') {
        return 'E-mail or Password invalid.';
      } else if (e.code == 'too-many-requests') {
        return 'Login failed, exceed requests try again soon.';
      }
    }
  }

  void _navigateToNextScreen(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage()),
    );
  }

  void showCircularIndicator(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Color(0xFF0ca886)),
          );
        });
  }

  Future<String?> getCountryForUser(User? user) async {
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore
        .instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .get();
    if (snapshot.exists) {
      return snapshot.data()?['country'];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to retrieve the Firestore field in AuthPage but I couldn't use it to validate on the Login page, so I'm in this dilemma and would like to understand if anyone can help me. Thank you...

Comment: There's quite some code in your question. Without repeating the whole use-case, which specific line in the code you shared doesn't work?  Is there any error message?

Comment: Yes, the code is the initial one because I've already tried several ways and haven't found anything that works. I am unable to validate the country I selected with the one registered in Firebase Storage. I'm trying like this now...

Comment: Plee edit your question to contain a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example. Also note that "I couldn't" and "I am unable to" are really hard to help with. Once you isolate the **first** line that doesnt' work, can you `print` the value that is not what you expected and show both that `print` statement and its output in the question?

Comment: I'm sorry for the way I asked, I'm new here but it's a question that's bothering me because I don't have a specific error. The problem would be in the logic of how to take a field in Firebase Storage and use it to validate a login, as the code sent contains country, email and password, how to use the country registered in Firebase Store and use it to validate the Login. if. if. if. if. To access the registered field, the user would first need to authenticate to access the field, but using it for validation is the problem.